# sqlalchemy results to dictionary

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy

I stucked again. I have a sqlalchemy query

```
result = db.session.query(e.name.label('event_name'), u1.name.label('player1'), u2.name.label('player2'), s.when_do_they_play)\
.outerjoin(u1, u1.id == s.player1)\
.outerjoin(u2, u2.id == s.player2)\
.outerjoin(e, e.id == s.event_id).all()
```

which gives me following results

```
event_name      player1     player2     when_do_they_play
event1          player1     player2     2019-08-30@21:00
event2          player2     player3     2019-08-31@21:00
```

and I want to present it in form of table

```
    event1
player1 vs player2  2019-08-30@21:00
    event2
player2 vs player3  2019-08-31@21:00
```

I thought it would be a good idea to put initial results into dictionary

```
scheduled_json={}
for ldata in result:
    scheduled_json[ldata.event_name]={}
    scheduled_json[ldata.event_name]=ldata.event_name
    scheduled_json[ldata.event_name]['player1']={}
    scheduled_json[ldata.event_name]['player1']=ldata.player1
    scheduled_json[ldata.event_name]['player2']=ldata.player2
    scheduled_json[ldata.event_name]['when_do_they_play']=ldata.when_do_they_play
```

and then produce table inside my template.html using jinja2 for loop with some exceptions/ifs, but no. Flask won't let me do that because:

```
[...]
    scheduled_json[ldata.event_name]['player1']={}
TypeError: 'unicode' object does not support item assignment
```

obviously. So I'm thinking this can be resolved either on Python side (with use of marshmallow) or to utilize some jinja2 magic. Both are not know well to me, so what would be the best way to handle this problem? Of course, code examples are more than welcome.

Comment: `scheduled_json[ldata.event_name]=ldata.event_name` seems a bit odd.

Comment: great catch Ilja, problem was also fixed after removing that line

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured it out and this [solution](http://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#groupby) is sufficient for now.

```
<ul>
{% for group in scheduled_events|groupby('event_name') %}
    <li>{{ group.grouper }}<ul>
    {% for event in group.list %}
        <li>{{ event.player1 }} {{ event.player2 }} {{ event.when_do_they_play }}</li>
    {% endfor %}</ul></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

However I think sooner or later this data will be needed in JSON format so I decided to go with

```
return jsonify(result))
```